# How do I spy on Methods in a vuex subscriber?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

In created() of the Vue Component, I have a subscriber that subscribes to a Mutation of a Vuex store.
I tried to spy on a method that is called when the subscriber is triggered.
This is my first intuitive try:

```
//Vue-Component
created(){
     this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.type === "mutationname") {
        this.methodToBeSpiedOn();
      }
    });
}

//jest
import Component from "..."; 
...
const setSelectedCompanySpy = jest.spyOn(
    Component.methods,
    "methodToBeSpiedOn"
);
componentwrapper.vm.$store.commit("mutationname") 
expect(methodToBeSpiedOn).toBeCalled();
```

Now I thought, maybe it's because of Reactivity and the test needs more time to trigger the subscriber and so on.

So I tried using a setTimeout():

```
setTimeout(() => {
     expect(methodToBeSpiedOn).toBeCalled();
     done();
}, 10000);
```

But this does not work either.

So my question is: How do I spy on a method that is called in a Vuex subscriber?

Or is my approach completely wrong, and I shouldn't test subscribers like this?

Answer (score 1):

`Component.methods` on spyOn may not work because the `vm` is the main object where your component's methods are assigned.

Use the `vm`, like following example:

```
const setSelectedCompanySpy = jest.spyOn(
    componentwrapper.vm,
    "methodToBeSpiedOn"
);

expect(setSelectedCompanySpy).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1. Suppose you test the created Lifecyclehook. In that case the function that I spy on will be executed before componentwrapper.vm exists. What do I do in that case? Because I tried your approach but the test still fails.  2. I used Component.methods for non subscriber cases where spyon worked fine.

Comment: @telion for the created lifecycle to finish, you can use `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` and after that, add your `expect`